# How to show picture inside CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact:)

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

How would I get an image inside `CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact:)`

I tried something like this:

```
    fileprivate func showUnknownContactViewController() {
    let aContact = CNMutableContact()
    let newEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: email! as NSString)
    aContact.emailAddresses.append(newEmail)

    let workPhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue : phone!))
    aContact.phoneNumbers.append(workPhone)

    aContact.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePicture.image!)

    //Pushing controller...
    }
```

Trying to add the image like this:

> ```
>     aContact.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePicture.image!)
> ```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I could not find any other solutions, therefore I am asking: Is there a way to show a picture inside `CNContactViewController`?

This is how I want it to be:
[image: Image of shrek]

Answer (score 2):

So after a little bit of research with [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt), I found out that the issue was caused because the contact I was showing was an existing contact.

Comment: The picture was already set because I had the same data already in contacts. It somehow recognizes it and shows the original contact in contacts.

Comment: Did you find a way to force a different picture onto the CNContactViewController? I have contacts who share a main office number, and the wrong picture will show if just one of them is already in the users contacts.

Comment: I haven't tested with office number, but I did not figure out a way to force it anyways. It could be against Apple´s policy and get your app restricted.

Comment: There is/was a bug with CNContactViewController showing the photo for any existing contact that matches via email address, even if you are using `forUnknownContact` - I reported this to Apple and it seems to have been addressed in iOS 13 beta 7